# HTML динамическое заполнение <select> используя GET параметр

Tags: javascript, html, get

Подскажите можно ли реализовать?

есть ссылка http://localhost/auth.html?name=myName

есть страница с формой , которую необходимо заполнить
в зависимости от значения "name".

Т. е. для значения name=myName

```
    <select>
     <option value="odin">Odin</option>
    </select>
```

для значения name=youName

```
    <select>
     <option value="Dva">dva</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Подсказываю - можно. Но зачем?

Comment: А Вам нужно именно разные `option` или разные дефолтные `option` в зависимости от `$_GET` параметра ?

Comment: мне необходимо уменьшить количество отображаемой информации, в зависимости от нужд пользователя. то есть изначально в моем _select_ 20 строк, а я хочу чтобы пользователь видел только те с которыми работает он - это от 1 до 4 _option_

Comment: Нашел такое решение. Не отличается изяществом и не совсем то что мне надо.
Скрывает выбор в зависимости от параметра. При этом обращается к _value_ а у меня они все должны быть уникальны так что обратится бы к другому атрибуту 
    
    `function optHide() {
   var url = location.search.split('name=')[1]
   var opt= document.getElementsByTagName('option');
   var res;
   for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (opt[i].value == url) {
     opt[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
   }
  }`